# Add jquery slider to form field in ZF2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2, zend-form

It seems that modifying how a form is rendered has become more complicated since ZF1 - there are no decorators anymore. What I want to achieve is to add a jquery slider to a normal input form field.

A normal input field renders as follows for me:

```
<label>Your Net Income</label>
<input type="text" name="net_income" value="1500">
```

What I want is something like that:

```
<label>Your Net Income</label>
<div id="slider" class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider-input">
    <input type="text" name="net_income" value="1500">
</div>
```

So a div is added left to the input field for the slide. Also, I would need to execute some JS to initialize the slider like this:

```
var $slider = $("#slider");
if ($slider.length > 0) {
    $slider.slider({
        min: 500,
        max: 5000,
        step: 100,
        value: 1500,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("input").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
}
```

What is the best way to get this done in ZF2? I see several options:

- Modify the form via jquery and prepend the slider.
- Create a custom form element in ZF2
- Overload and modify the input form element in ZF

Any recommendations? Modifying via JS doesn't seem to be very robust. But creating a custom form element seems to be complicated. In ZF2 I would probably just added a decorator or replaced the viewscript of the individual element. But now the form does not come across very handy.

Thank you for any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using `formCollection()`, it is very simple. Just do it like this in your view:

```
<?= $this->formLabel($element); ?>
<div id="slider" class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider-input">
  <?= $this->formElement($element); ?>
</div>
```

And if you do use `formCollection()` just loop through your form:

```
foreach ($form as $element)
{
  if($element->getName() == 'net_income')
  {
    // do as I mentioned
  }
  else
  {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

More :
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html